# Laravel: why form::model not work with section -> yield?

Tags: laravel

In edit.blade.php I have:

```
@section('additionalInputs')
    {!! Form::select('gender') !!}
@stop


@section('content')
    @include('backend.admin.user.form', ['formRoute' => ['backend.admin.user.update', $user->id], 'formMethod' => 'PUT'])
@stop
```

In backend.admin.user.form.blade.php I have:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['route' => $formRoute, 'method' => $formMethod, 'class'=>'no-inline-edit']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('first_name') !!}
    {!! Form::text('last_name') !!}
    @yield('additionalInputs')
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

first_name and last_name are filled with data, why gender is not populated ?

If I put like this:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['route' => $formRoute, 'method' => $formMethod, 'class'=>'no-inline-edit']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('first_name') !!}
    {!! Form::text('last_name') !!}
    {!! Form::select('gender') !!}
    @yield('additionalInputs')
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

first gender is populated, second is not...

Answer (score 0):

The 1st argument of a Form::select is the input's name.
For a select input to be generated you need to provide array of data like the example below.

```
{!! Form::select('gender', [
     'male' => 'Male',
     'female' => 'Female'
      ])
!!}
```

or pass a $genders var through your controller to your view

```
{!! Form::select('gender', $genders) !!}
```